# Change selectMenu option programmatically in child inAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, triggers

I open a window using javascript `window.open()`

The window that opens has the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#lang").change(function(){
        var lname = jQuery(this).val().split("-");
        window.location = '<?php echo JURI::root();?>index.php?lang='+lname[0];
        alert(lname[0]);
        alert('lang '+lang);
    });
```

Now this code is triggered upon 'lang' select menu change. I open the window programmatically using `window.open` and I managed to populate data into the window fields using `Window.executeScript()`. For example this works for me:

```
loginWindow.executeScript({
   code: "jQuery('input#username').val('10500050')"
});
```

However, when I tried to follow the same logic for changing the selected item in selectMenu called 'lang' for the same window, I failed.

**Attempts**

I tried all the following lines in `executeScript`;

```
code: "$('#lang').val('ms')"
code: "jQuery('#lang option[value=ms]').prop('selected', true)"
code: "jQuery('#lang').selectmenu('value', 'ms')"
```

with these in the next `executeScript` to trigger change

```
code: "$('#lang').trigger('change')"
code: "$('#lang').selectmenu('refresh', true)"
code: "jQuery('#lang').selectmenu('refresh')"
code: "jQuery('#lang').selectmenu('change')"
code: "$('#lang').change()"
```

None of them helped. I'm not sure if I should combine them in one `executeScript`. I do not know how to do that. The window that opens is from different domain.

Am I missing something here?

The entire code on the opener side is as follows:

```
loginWindow.addEventListener( 'loadstop', function() {
    alert('test');
    var loop = setInterval(function() {
       loginWindow.executeScript({
          code: "jQuery('input#username').val('10500050')"
          },
          function( values ) {
             var give = values[ 0 ];
             if ( give ) {
                clearInterval( loop );
                giveMeUsername(); 
              }
          });

        loginWindow.executeScript({
           code: "  jQuery('input#name').val('10500050')"
            },
            function( values ) {
               var give = values[ 0 ];
                  if ( give ) {
                     clearInterval( loop );
                     giveMeUsername(); 
                   }
             });

        loginWindow.executeScript({
           //code: "$('#lang').val('zh')"
           //code: "jQuery('#lang option[value=ms]').prop('selected', true)"
           code: "jQuery('#lang').selectmenu('value', 'ms')"
           //code: "localStorage.setItem( 'lan', 'ms' )"
           },
           function( values ) {
              var give = values[ 0 ];
              if ( give ) {
                 clearInterval( loop );
                 giveMeUsername(); 
               }
            });

      loginWindow.executeScript({
         //code: "$('#lang').trigger('change')"
         //code: "$('#lang').selectmenu('refresh', true)"
         //code: "jQuery('#lang').selectmenu('refresh')"
         //code: "jQuery('#lang').selectmenu('change')"
         code: "$('#lang').change()"
         },
         function( values ) {
            var give = values[ 0 ];
            if ( give ) {
               clearInterval( loop );
               giveMeUsername(); 
             }
           });                        
     });
});
```

The first two `executeScript` work fine. But the last two (selectMenu part) do not work. Nothing occurs.

**UPDATE**

When add this code to the window itself, it works and the select box value is changed:

```
jQuery("#lang option[value='zh-TW']").attr("selected","selected");
jQuery('#lang').change();
```

However, when I add it inside `executeScript` in the parent window (opener), it does not work!

Comment: You should be able to put all of thos executeScript calls together by separating commands using semi-colons. I don't think that this would solve the issue anyway.

Comment: @jlreymendez semi-colon did not work for me, but comma worked. Thanks for point out the possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code works when I paste it directly in the child window inside `jQuery(document).ready(function()`, I assumed it should work from the parent window using `executeScript`. After many trial and error experiments, the following code worked for me:

```
                    loginWindow.executeScript(
                        {
                            code: "jQuery('#lang option[value=zh-TW]').attr('selected','selected'), jQuery('#lang').change()"                               
                        });
```

Which is the same code I mentioned in "Update" part of my question, except the difference in single quote and double quote. Here using `executeScript`, I had to manipulate to use double quote only to enclose the entire injected code, the rest I use single quote.

The code above, change the option selected in select box in child window using `executeScript` method in parent window (opener).